# ValueError with randint

Tags: python

I'm having this really weird error and I have no idea what it is. 
This is my code:

```
def wordChoice():
    theme = themechoice
    word = theme[randint(0, len(theme) - 1)]
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\USB Backup\Python\Hangman.py", line 31, in wordChoice
            word = theme[randint(0, len(theme) - 1)]
          File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\random.py", line 218, in randint
            return self.randrange(a, b+1)
          File "C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\random.py", line 196, in randrange
            raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
        ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
```

I've searched everywhere but I can't find anything. I'm also kind of a newb so sorry if it was something obvious.

EDIT:

Before i set theme to this:

```
def themeChoice():
    n = 0
    for i in themes:
        n += 1
        print(str(n) + " - " + i)
    themechoice = themesToThemes[themes[int(input("Type the number corresponding to your chosen theme: ")) - 1]]
    print (themechoice)
```

Comment: You're asking for `randint(0, 0)`. It seems that `len(theme)` is 1, therefore no random number can be generated in [0; 0[

Comment: This is what you get from `randint(0,-1)`, which is converted to `randrange(0,0)`. The solution is not to try and get a random number in that range, because it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

This error will occur when `theme` is empty.

```
>>> theme = []
>>> random.randint(0, len(theme)-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Programming\Python 3.5\lib\random.py", line 218, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Programming\Python 3.5\lib\random.py", line 196, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
```

Make sure `theme` actually has elements in it before trying to randomly choose an element from it. Also, consider using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) instead of manually generating an index with `randint`.